# Table align="center" doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

Why would the align="center" not be working on the first table on the page below:

http://eurochlor.amaze.com/chlorinated-solvents-%28ecsa%29/about-chlorinated-solvents/facts-figures/trichloroethylene.aspx

Comment: Please specify what you want: centering the table itself, or the text inside the cells

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set this on the <td> elements.

You should also use text-align: center in css, not align="center" in html.

Comment: It is a limitation of the rich text editor (tinymce) I am using. Could you explaing what you mean by "You need to set this on the elements." please?

Comment: Do you want to center the Table itself, or the text inside the cells?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have the table centered use:

```
.content-table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if you want to have the td text centered use:

```
.content-table td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

while there are many ways to do with css, divs, and style property and stuff
the simpliest way is not to use align="center" but to wrap the table in `<center> </center>` tag :)

*Note*: the `center` element is considered [obsolete in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements).

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS selector with Attribute align="center" like below:

```
table[align="center"] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two things you need to do

1. need to have width in pixel or %
2. margin: 0 auto; or i.e margin-left:auto & margin-right:auto

   .search-box table{
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   margin: auto;
   }